# Glassfish JVM settings for GC

Tags: java, glassfish, jvm

I am running an application on my glassfish server and I have following JVM settings (which I think are relevant to my question): `-Xmx512m -XX:NewRatio=2 -XX:+UseParallelOldGC -XX:+UseParallelGC` all other setting are default. I have been testing server performance with JMC (Java Mission Control) for last 48 hours and I noticed this: PS Old Gen has about 341 MB of heap, PS Eden has about 143MB of heap, PS Surviovor has about 13MB of heap (is this enough or should I use different SurvivorRatio?)

Graph shows that on the beginning java heap has about 200MB of allocated space, but after each full GC it grows so now is around 450MB, even heap used (after each full GC) drops down to around 100MB and than slowly grows until next minor GC/full GC... Why is committed java heap (red line) increasing? Is this normal behaviour? Will it stop when it reach 512MB? Should I use -Xms512m that committed java heap would be 512MB from start?

[image]

And now about garbage collections:
Minor GC (PS Scavenge) runs about every 1 minute and has duration around 10-30ms. Full GC (PS MarkSweep) runs about every 14-18hours and first it had duration of 200ms but the last had duration of 20 seconds (I don't know why there are so big difference in duration)! I am wondering if this is ok and how to get better results? Should I use `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC` or maybe even `-XX:+UseG1GC`? If I use any of these GC will I have to increase max heap size (I read that UseG1GC is for larger heaps only)? Do I have to change any other setting to besides the type of GC (like SurvivorRatio, NewRation,...)?

Does GC Duration in JMC equals to stop the world pause time (or is pause time shorter)? So if I had 20second GC Duration of full GC does that mean that my server was unresponsive for 20second? I have JAX-RS on my server and I call one of them every 10 seconds using ajax (timeout is 10seconds) so that means that at least 2 calls won't be successful? What is the status of ajax call in this case (maybe an error)? I have to warn users about error calls and I don't know what do to in this case if an error was the result of GC pause....

If I had -Xmx1024m (so two times bigger than now) full GC would be rarer but would it last even more time?

I read a lot of articles about JVM and JVM GC but I still don't know what I have to do that all setting would be optimal for my application (I am concerned about last 20 second long GC duration)...

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 4):

> Full GC (PS MarkSweep) runs about every 14-18hours and first it had duration of 200ms but the last had duration of 20 seconds

Try setting a pause time goal via `-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis`.

> Should I use -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC or maybe even -XX:+UseG1GC?

Those certainly would be an option, but since the parallel collector seems to be able to provide decent latency initially and only gets worse as the old gen increases you might not need to

> Graph shows that on the beginning java heap has about 200MB of allocated space, but after each full GC it grows so now is around 450MB, even heap used (after each full GC) drops down to around 100MB and than slowly grows until next minor GC/full GC... Why is committed java heap (red line) increasing?

Because you're using the parallel collector, which has throughput as its primary goal (possibly at the detriment of memory footprint or latency if no limits on those are specified). And it can provide the highest throughput by by collecting rarely when lots of garbage has accumulated.

By providing it with a pause time goal it will stop growing the heap if it becomes too big to meet the pause time goal.

> If I had -Xmx1024m (so two times bigger than now) full GC would be rarer but would it last even more time?

Possibly, but the GC will stop growing the heap once it cannot meet the `MaxHeapFreeRatio` goal anymore.

Comment: So if I set -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis to 5000 will GC intervals be shorter so that GC could complete in 5 seconds? What if GC does not complete in 5 seconds? Would you recommend me to set Xms to 512m (same as Xmx) in relation to optimize GC duration? Is default value of MaxHeapFreeRatio ok (70%)?

Comment: Can you please also explain me usage of -XX:GCPauseIntervalMillis=X and -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=X? If I set these values to 500ms and 50ms does that mean that GC duration will be maximum 50ms? What does the first option (GCPauseIntervalMillis) do? Do I need to set both or just MaxGCPauseMillis? What are possible threats if I set those two parameters? And the last querstion: if I set  -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC can I get worst GC results or there are no disadvantages ?Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why don't you just try it out, maybe combined with a load test? you also might want to read the [Java 8 GC Tuning Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/)

Comment: Ok I run some tests during the last 7 days with  XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC and -XX:+UseParNewGC (without -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis). The last CMS Final Remark phase took 80 seconds, while all previous phases (Final Remark and Initial) last maximum of 2 seconds (there were around 10 of CMS). What could be the reason of such behaviour? I didn't set -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis because I read somewhere that it may cause low throughput. I also read that I could use  -XX:+UseLargePagesInMetaspace option but it could cause memory usage regressions so I don't know if I should use it.

Comment: "because I read somewhere that it may cause low throughput". It trades ___some___ throughput for pause times. You have to choose your tradeoff, you can't have everything at once. If you are concerned about pause times (your question indicates you are) then you should set a goal. I think I have answered your initial question, if you choose to ignore it I can't really help you. If you have in-depth questions about CMS you probably should make a new question

Comment: Ok, I'll try to set -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis to 5000ms (which is OK for me) and I'll see results after few days. I have one more question for you - I read somewhere that XX:+UseG1GC is more appropriate for larger heap size. How about smaller heap size (like 512m)? Is it possible that using this GC type will result in poorer performance? Why we don't use UseG1GC as the first GC type option?